# Is Science Publishing group (http://www.sciencepg.net) a genuine publisher related to the Science journal?

Tags: publications, publishers, science, disreputable-publishers

I received an email requesting me to apply for a reviewer/editor position at [Science Publishing group](http://www.sciencepg.net). But I found that Science Publications have a [different website](http://thescipub.com/), hence I feel that the email is a fraud. Please help to clarify matters.

Comment: Science Publishing != Science Publications would be my first guess... It doesn't look like one of the sites is trying to copy the other one, they have different journals, etc. So I'd guess that this is just an ordinary publisher, spamming people to get reviewers/editors, which happens rather regularly. As I'm just guessing from the websites and I don't know either publisher, I will leave this as a comment rather than an answer...

Comment: Looks like it's a predatory publisher, see this list: http://beallslist.weebly.com/

Comment: I'm not particularly impressed by [this paper](http://thescipub.com/PDF/jmssp.2016.271.276.pdf), which I found by looking through the titles of one of the mathematics journals. The editing is poor -- even a basic electronic spell check would have caught some misspellings. The results are not very deep -- most any beginning graduate student could come up with the proofs. No motivation is given for why one would be interested in this particular metric space generalization and the generalization they study is not compared with any other generalized metric space notion.

Comment: Still better than the their newest publication in statistics and actuarial science, http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/pdf/10.11648.j.ijsas.20170103.15.pdf

Comment: @Stephan Sturm: I have to agree. Your example beats mine hands down: *The study of DNA in relation to Cosmos, and in turn to Vedic Astrology, may open new doors in understanding the planets’ role in bringing about a particular event in life.*

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? Whether or not "Science Publishing Group" is the publisher of the magazine "Science" is a simple matter of fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/) is the official magazine of the American Association for the Advancement of Science, which has nothing to do with two publishers you mentioned. It is common these days that new publishers (usually publishing online open access journals) use the names, which are similar to the famous publications.

Science and Nature are the most reputable journals (though they are technically magazines) in cutting-edge research. Both have impact factors over 30. The publishers you mentioned publish journals, which are not even properly indexed. Most of the journals by such publishers have an impact factor of around 1 (just mentioned to highlight the difference).

In any case, no reputable publisher asks you to apply. They choose their editors/reviewers directly based on your works. When an email asks you to apply, this is a general advertisement email sent to a long mailing list.

Comment: They are not "new publishers".  I know because they have been emailing me for years.  Do not work with them.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist new in comparison with AAAS or other old publishers. These 'new' publishers have formed in the era of online publishing industry.

Comment: "Science and Nature are the most reputable journals" That depends very much on your field.