# Is "Cambridge Scholars" a fake publisher?

Tags: publications

Considering the fact that I'm a graduate student with a couple of publications, here is the email I've recently received from [this website](http://www.cambridgescholars.com/) (I found it in my spam folder):

> Dear Dr. Robotocist, ------------> (I'm not a doctor!!!)
>
> Firstly, please excuse this unsolicited email.
> I’m sure that like me you receive too many as it is and so I’ll keep
> it brief.
>
> I was recently appointed as Commissioning Editor for
> Cambridge Scholars Publishing with a brief to expand the subject areas
> in which we publish books. As such I am in the process of developing a
> collection based in the field of Robotics. As I believe you already
> have some experience of academic and scientific writing, I wondered
> whether you would consider us as your publisher should you decide to
> put ‘pen to paper’ and write a book at some point in the future?
>
> We
> are also developing Editorial Advisory Groups to help ensure that we
> only publish high quality texts. If this is something that you would
> like to become involved in, please do let me know. As I promised, I
> have kept this message short, but would be delighted to talk or
> correspond more if you feel you would like to explore possibilities.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Helen Edwards
>
> Commissioning Assistant

To me, *this is a miserable fake thing*, and I just wanted to know whether or not anybody has encountered this organization before.

Comment: I don't know that specific publisher, but there are a couple of related questions here, including [With Beall's List gone, how can I tell if a journal is spam?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83764/with-bealls-list-gone-how-can-i-tell-if-a-journal-is-spam). Generally, the use of the Cambridge name while being not associated with Cambridge University is a darkly red flag for me.

Comment: I now found the "Advisory Board" on the website: At least in my research field, the "highly respected academics" are total nobodies (no offense intended).

Comment: If you get a mail from a publisher asking for submissions or similar it's a predetory, fake or at least terrible publisher/journal. Except for invited papers publishers of good journals won't write to you asking for submissions.

Comment: I looked at the titles in mathematics, and while they skew heavily towards the philosophy and social sciences, the two I looked at more closely don't come close to the Beall'ness found [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94007) (see the comments). In particular, to me [this book](http://www.cambridgescholars.com/from-foundations-to-philosophy-of-mathematics-14) seems at first glance to be scholarly --- see [this excerpt](http://www.cambridgescholars.com/download/sample/58876). **(continued)**

Comment: This book was also reviewed by Mathematical Reviews (MR3026739; publisher's summary only) and [by zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1275.03008), although the fact that the author has no other publications reviewed by either of these two reviewing journals is a red flag. But maybe the book is based on the author's graduate work, and the author had to leave this field due to lack of jobs. This doesn't show the author is a crank, but it does show a lack of prominence that might warrant further investigation.